# How to add domain in many2one fields on odoo?

Tags: odoo-14

How to add a domain in many2one fields on Odoo?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Ql4.png)

Answer (score 0):

A [domain](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#search-domains) is a list of criteria, each criterion being a triple (either a list or a tuple) of `(field_name, operator, value)` where the `field_name`should be a field name (str) of the current model, or a relationship traversal through a [Many2one](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2one) using dot-notation e.g. `street` or `partner_id.country`

if `mitra_price_list` is a field in `isd.res.partner.price_list` model, change your domain as follow:

```
[('mitra_price_list', '=', line.partner_id.id)]
```

`mitra_price_list` should be a relational field referencing the partner model.

I can see that you returned the domain inside a for loop, you can remove the for loop, use [mapped](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.mapped) to get the list of ids and change the operator to `in`:

***Example:***

```
[('mitra_price_list', 'in', selected_lines.mapped('partner_id.id')]
```